# If $a^b+b^a=800$, then find $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've solved many of this type of equations (without steps) by noticing certain pattern in the answers.

Can someone please give the answer with proper steps.
P.S. I know the answer will be $799$ and $1$ but I'm asking for the steps.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b\ge 2$, then $a,b\le 10$, because otherwise $a^b+b^a> 2^{10}>800$. So we have to check the pairs $(a,b)$ with $2\le a\le b\le 10$, which give no solution.

Comment: The OP did not specify integer solutions.

Comment: He also did not specify anything else about $a,b$. His own answer looked so "integral".

Answer (score 2):

For any equation of the form $a^b+b^a=k$ where $k \in \mathbb{C}$ there is at least one solution given by: $$a=k-1$$$$b=1$$ as $(k-1)^1+1^{(k-1)}=k-1+1=k$.
One can also swap $a,b$ to give another solution:$$a=1$$$$b=k-1$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $a\in (0, 799]$ there exists a real number $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a^b+b^a = 800$.

To see why, let $f(b):=a^b+b^a$.  Now $f(1) = a + 1<800$.  Also, $f(b)>b^a$ and $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} b^a = +\infty$.  These two facts plus the fact that $f$ is continuous imply that there exits a real number $b$ such that $f(b)=800$ (see [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)).

(Actually, if $a$ is any real greater than zero and then there still exists a positive real number $b$ where a^b+b^a=800, but the proof is a little more tricky.)

- If a=2, then b is approximately 9.47224.
- If a=3, then b is approximately 5.82613.
- If a=4, then b is approximately 4.37832.
- If a=5, then b is approximately 3.49605.
- If a=6, then b is approximately 2.91562.
- If a=7, then b is approximately 2.52955.
- If a=8, then b is approximately 2.2636.
- If a=9, then b is approximately 2.07237.
- If a=10, then b is approximately 1.92944.

All the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying $a^b+b^a=800$ lie on the smooth curve shown below.

[image]